# Ayuda con un option selected

Tags: php, mysql, html5, poo

En estos select quiero cargar la información correspondiente para ambos, pero también quiero que los select de países y ciudades, se coloque el país y ciudad selected que el usuario tiene registrado en la base de datos, por el momento ambas funciones me funcionan perfectamente mostrando los países y luego las ciudades según el país que seleccione, pero ahora quiero que si ya estan registrados en la bd, vengan selected, en cada función recibo el `id_pais` y `id_ciudad` en las variables `$GLOBALS`, que son los id del país y ciudad que ese usuario tiene registrado en la bd, espero puedan ayudarme

```
public function SelectPaisescontroller(){
    $id_pais=$GLOBALS['id_pais'];
    $respuesta = Datos::SelectPaisesModel("pais");
    echo '<select  class="form-control" name="id_pais" id="id_pais" value="'.$id_pais.'">';
    echo '<option value="'.$id_pais.'">'.$respuesta['PaisNombre'].'</option>';
        foreach ($respuesta as $row => $item){
        echo '<option value="'.$item['id_pais'].'">'.utf8_encode($item['PaisNombre']).'</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';

    }

public function SelectCiudadescontroller($datos=null){

    $datosController = $datos;
    $id_ciudad=$GLOBALS['id_ciudad'];
    echo '<select  class="form-control" name="id_ciudad" id="id_ciudad" value="'.$id_ciudad.'">';
    echo '<option value="0">Seleccione</option>';

    $respuesta = Datos::SelectCiudadesModel($datosController, "ciudad");

    foreach ($respuesta as $row => $item) {

        echo '<option value="'.$item['id_ciudad'].'">'.utf8_encode($item['CiudadNombre']).'</option>';

        }
    echo '</select>';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

No recomiendo el uso de variable Globales y menos aun en clases ya que van encontra de la abstracción

En cualquier caso puedes crear un condicional y decidir si es **selected** o no:

```
<?php

public function SelectPaisescontroller()
{
    $id_pais = $GLOBALS['id_pais'];
    $respuesta = Datos::SelectPaisesModel("pais");
    // select no tiene atributo value
    echo '<select  class="form-control" name="id_pais" id="id_pais">';
    //echo '<option value="'.$id_pais.'">'.$respuesta['PaisNombre'].'</option>';
    echo '<option value="0">Seleccione</option>';
        foreach ($respuesta as $row => $item)
        {
            if($item['id_pais'] == $id_pais){
                echo '<option value="'.$item['id_pais'].'" selected>'.utf8_encode($item['PaisNombre']).'</option>';             
            }
            else{
                echo '<option value="'.$item['id_pais'].'">'.utf8_encode($item['PaisNombre']).'</option>';
            }
        }
        echo '</select>';
}

public function SelectCiudadescontroller($datos=null)
{
    $datosController = $datos;
    $id_ciudad = $GLOBALS['id_ciudad'];
    // select no tiene atributo value
    echo '<select  class="form-control" name="id_ciudad" id="id_ciudad">';
    echo '<option value="0">Seleccione</option>';

    $respuesta = Datos::SelectCiudadesModel($datosController, "ciudad");

    foreach ($respuesta as $row => $item)
    {
        if($item['id_ciudad'] == $id_ciudad){
            echo '<option value="'.$item['id_ciudad'].'" selected>'.utf8_encode($item['CiudadNombre']).'</option>';
        }
        else{
            echo '<option value="'.$item['id_ciudad'].'">'.utf8_encode($item['CiudadNombre']).'</option>';
        }
    }
    echo '</select>';
}
```